# CouchDB query performance

Tags: performance, couchdb

If the number of documents is more will the querying of data gets slower in CouchDB?

Example Scenario:

- I have a combobox in a form for customer name. When the user types the customer name, I have to do autofilling.
- There will be around 10k customer documents in the CouchDB. I understand that i have to create a view to do the same.
- CouchDB database is in the local machine where the application resides.

Question: 
Will it take more than 2 - 3 seconds to query the DB for matching customer names? 
Will querying take more time for each query if there are many documents in the CouchDB (say around 100000 documents)?

Any pointers on how to create views/index will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The view runs on every document, but only once. After that, the document's view value(s) are stored forever. Fetching a customer by name will be very fast because you would normally have only a few new documents to process in the view at query time.

Query time will not increase noticeably if you have more documents. Technically, access times grow logarithmically with the number of documents. However, in practice fetching documents is basically constant time and very unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: Hi @JasonSmith, is there a way to tackle the problem of slow first time performance? I've definitely seen the first hit on the view takes forever (dealing with 10k documents in one view). Is there a way to detect if the view has been run before/ doing this for the first time?

Comment: @Bundeeteddee You can add the ?stale=update_after option, which will return whatever is in the view immediately, and it will start refreshing the view in the background. That will do a trade-off: you get an answer immediately, but it may not be the very latest data. Alternatively, you can query _canges?feed=continuous and then you can query the view whenever CouchDB notifies you that a change has happened. That takes a bit of work but that is the most surefire way