# time series logging/statistics - scalable solution

Tags: java, mongodb, scalability, key-value, nosql

It`s quite usual to query database or log files for uptime information or for number of requests per given time interval.

As you gather more and more data SQL queries or log crawling becomes slower and slower (imagine 10 million table rows / log lines).

Typical questions :

- How many tasks we processed in last x months ?
- What was availability of our service in last X time period ?
- Is average number of requests in last hour higher than in last 1 day average ?

I would like to use some key-value storage : many buckets with different auto-expiration - so we could look into e.g. 10min/1hr/1day buckets and sum all items there and proudly say "in last 10 minutes we processed 10^6 requests".

I am sure that MongoDB or Redis offer time expiration in buckets - i am just a bit worried whether implementation will be straightforward.

How would you solve this ? Do you know better tools for this task ?

*(our project is written in java and python)*

Comment: My first thought was to use some AOP to capture the KPI data that you want, but with using python as well I guess it would not work.  Some clients of mine are using Zabbix (http://www.zabbix.com/) for capture of Mysql and Webserver KPI.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different conceptual approach ...

Let's imagine you have a log table that logs request. Here is how I would solve the problem of reporting off of the log data:

1. Start storing log data in a table.
2. Once the log table gets to 1 million records, you ship the entire table off to a data warehouse. Basically "archiving" the data so slower queries can hit it later.
3. Take an aggregation snapshot offline of the data you just archived. Run a job that gets the numbers you're looking for.
4. Write code to merge real time queries and - if need be - archived queries.

The big picture idea is that the log data is static once it's done. You can run an aggregation over the data once and it will *never* change.  So why do it real time every time?

You want to make your real time data very small and fast. Older data either has quick lookup's for known aggregations or the processing takes longer.

Answer (score 0):

[CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) secondary indexes / views expose your data in [O(log n) time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588387/couchdb-query-performance), and are effortless to implement and interact with since the whole thing sits behind a RESTful HTTP API. Check it out:

- One secondary index indexes your log events by when they were created, and reduces them to a count using, well, the builtin `_count` reduce function.
- Another secondary index might only index log events indicating downtime, or uptime, or 500s, or unicorns. The key is, they're all like 3-line functions that run logarithmically.
- By queries with `startkey=[timestamp for X days ago]`, you can count only the log entries since that moment.
- By querying with `reduce=false`, you can return the log entries themselves, keyed by creation date.
- Use other builtin reduce functions like `_stats` to get, well, stats about your logs.

CouchDB has client libraries for [Java](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Java) and [Python](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Python), but in the end is just a RESTful HTTP API, so any HTTP library should do the trick just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RDDTool for that. http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/
IT is a very useful library for logging time-series data and create graphs with them.