# Which NoSQL solution lets us easily create an analytics product?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Assume we want to build a simple Google Analytics clone, tracking pageviews. We will place javascript on websites that tracks pageviews.

- Can the javascript dump data directly into the database without having to go through a server (preferred)?
- We obviously want to dump a lot of data in there. Billions of rows.
- Does the database scale easily with as little interference as possible? (DynamoDB's model is perfect: 0 overhead).
- Can we do somewhat flexible querying: limit by date, and filter/limit by a number of tags?

Answer (score 0):

> Can the javascript dump data directly into the database without having to go through a server (preferred)?

For the databases of which I'm aware, that would require browser clients having write access to the database, such that it would be trivial for an attacker to pollute your database with some simple JavaScript. If that's sufferable, then it's certainly possible. For something like [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/), you'd just make the DB globally writable (but not readable or editable), so clients can push events as they occur.

> Does the database scale easily with as little interference as possible? (DynamoDB's model is perfect: 0 overhead).

Cloudant specifically is built on [BigCouch](http://bigcouch.cloudant.com/), which the creators built to deal with systems generating petabytes of data per *second*. So, it scales. It uses Dynamo's concept of quorum to maximize consistency between nodes.

FYI: BigCouch is merging with CouchDB later this year.

> Can we do somewhat flexible querying: limit by date, and filter/limit by a number of tags?

CouchDB, BigCouch, and Cloudant all use MapReduce for queries, which build as your data enters the system, such that accessing the results of a MapReduce query occur in [O(log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588387/couchdb-query-performance) time. Each system also provides special methods for streaming information about changes to the database as changes occur, which is perfect for a dashboard.